# HAs anyone used pyoxidizer to create .exe file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyoxidizer

I have created the .toml file called pyoxidizer.toml in the same folder where the script are placed.

but when I run on the command file in the same folder where all the .py files (and the .toml file) are kept

```
pyoxidizer build
```

I get the error

```
error: unable to find PyOxidizer config file at .
```

I have checked multiple times and it seems the .toml file is in the same folder yet I get this error.